# TypeScript - Can't "new" an interface for of an existing type

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I am trying to use RxJs definitions in TypeScript application I am writing. I imported the defs and now I am trying to new up a subject.

```
this.stream = new Rx.Subject();
```

However when I try this I get the following error.

> Error 6   The property 'Subject' does not exist on value of type '{
>   Internals: { inherits(child: Function, parent: Function): Function;
>   addProperties(obj: Object, ...sourcces: Object[]): void; addRef(xs:
>   Rx.IObservable, r: { getDisposable(): Rx._IDisposable; }):
>   Rx.IObservable; }; Observer: { create(onNext: (value: any) => void,
>   onError?: (exception: any) => void, onCompleted?: () => void):
>   Rx.IObserver; fromNotifier(handler: (notification: Rx.INotification)
>   => void): Rx.IObserver; }; }

When I look at the type defs for this I can see that the Subject class has been defined as an interface

```
export interface Subject {
    (): ISubject;

    create(observer: IObserver, observable: IObservable): ISubject;
}
```

Can someone tell me how I can create an instance of this Subject class as I cannot find a way to do it.  Currently using TS 9.1.1.  I thought the **(): ISubject** might do it but doesn't seem to have any impact.

I know some suggestions are to define a class instead but then I would need to implement all the methods from the base interfaces so this would be huge as it inherits from IObservable.

Comment: You can't create an interface. Is there a class defined somewhere that is a `Subject`?

Comment: This is a TS def file, RxJs does have a Subject ctor function which you can new up but I am battling the type system here.

Comment: Where'd you get the def file from? It's not the current one from the definitely typed libraries on GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the latest version of the [rx.js typing from Definitely Typed](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/rx.js/rx.d.ts) this works. Updating your definition is the way to go.

You can also try it on the TypeScript Playground - you'll need to paste in the code from Definitely Typed to test it out (long-links to the playground no longer seem to be allowed on here).

```
var x = new Rx.Subject();
```

Comment: Why is `Subject` still defined as an interface in the latest version of rx.d.ts? `export interface Subject<T> extends ISubject<T>`

Comment: Yes after updating my type definitions to a version compatible with 9.1.1. I was able to get this to work.